# How to avoid integrity errors occuring because of concurrent creations/updates?

Tags: python, django, database, postgresql, sqlalchemy

So let's say there's a model A which looks like this:

```
class A(model):
    name = char(unique=True)
```

When a user tries to create a new A, a view will check whether the name is already taken. Like that:

```
name_taken = A.objects.get(name=name_passed_by_user)
if name_taken:
    return "Name exists!"
# Creating A here
```

It used to work well, but as the system grew there started to appear concurrent attempts at creating A's with the same name. And sometimes multiple requests pass the "name exists check" in the same few milliseconds, resulting in integrity errors, since the name field has to be UNIQUE, and multiple requests to create a certain name pass the check.

The current solution is a lot of "try: except IntegrityError:" wraps around creation parts, despite the prior check. Is there a way to avoid that? Because there are a lot of models with UNIQUE constraints like that, thus a lot of ugly "try: except IntegrityError:" wraps. Is it possible to lock as to not prevent from SELECTing, but lock as to prevent from SELECTing FOR UPDATE? Or maybe there's a more proper solution? I'm certain it's a common problem with usernames and other fields/columns like them, and there must be a proper approach rather than exception catching.

The DB is Postgres10, ORM is SQLAlchemy of Python, but tweaks to db directly are applicable too.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing you can do is to set the appropriate [*transaction isolation*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/transaction-iso.html#XACT-REPEATABLE-READ) directly to postgres. Neither python nor the ORM can do anything about it. *serialized* level will most likely solve your problem. But it might slow down performance, so you should try *repeatable read* too.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Python, you should have heard of the “ask forgiveness, not permission” design principle.

To avoid the race condition you describe, simply try to add the new row to the table.
If you get a `unique_violation` (SQLSTATE `23505`), rollback the transaction and return that the name exists.

Comment: Thank you, it's indeed like that right now with all the try: except:'s and sessions.rollback()'s. Probably shouldn't change it, since it's one of the principles. Just thought it's a bad design pattern. Apparently not.